Lookup in excel from a range and returning the match
I am trying to work on this for quite a few days for now. I want to take out the middle names from last name. I have possible list of middle names and a list of last names. I am trying to look up the middle names and get them separated. I also have to do a length search for each record to see which middle name is fitting best because it is possible in some cases more them one middle name can match. The length of middle name column is just for information purpose, as it is taking the length with one space at the end.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You could try using the following formula to get the desired output as expected:


=MAP(A2:A12,LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(@SORT(FILTER(B2:C6,1-ISERR(SEARCH(" "&B2:B6," "&x&" ")),""),2,-1),"")))



does this work in excel? how to use it?

I have shown the screenshot with excel only so yes it does work with excel only.
